# create a folder in a grandparent dir vb.net

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net-2010, dir

I want to create a dir  (named with a varible `Utilities._Name`)located two levels from the exe file,

My exe file is in `C:\SGEA\SGEA\bin`
How can I do it so I get `C:\SGEA\theNewDir` without using full path, just relative paths?

```
If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Utilities._Name) Then
   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Utilities._Name)
Else
   MessageBox.Show("There is already a dir named: " & Utilities._Name, "SGEA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the path to the exe file, you can use the [System.IO.Path Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) to navigate easily:

```
Dim folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(theExeFile)
Dim grandparent = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(folder)) ' Up two directories

Dim newFolder = Path.Combine(grandparent, "theNewDir") ' Use this to create the new folder name cleanly

Utilities._Name = newFolder
```

Comment: Why is it better to use `Path.Combine(grandparent, "theNewDir")` instead of  ` System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory`

Comment: @cMinor You'd use `CreateDirectory` to create the directory - this builds the "path" you'd pass to `CreateDirectory` (the string)